# rewrite all requests except assets and favicon.* in nginx (for angular app)

Tags: regex, angularjs, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm currently rewriting each page to /index.html but that is going to be messy to maintain.

```
rewrite ^/(about)$  /index.html last;
```

I'd rather do something like:

```
rewrite ^/!(assets|favicon.*)$  /index.html last;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this regex:

```
rewrite ^/(?!assets|favicon) /index.html last;
```

Comment: so `/about` didn't get rewritten to `/index.html` ?

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.